# How to check email already exists in Supabase table for signup in flutter?

Tags: flutter, supabase

Here I tried to move from firebase to Supabase in my flutter project.
I stuck on first stage.
onPress register button,

```
final response = await Supabase.instance.client.auth.signUp(email,pass);
```

This is create new user in table.
But How could I check email already exist for signup ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edited

Long answer short, you should not have to find out if a user exists or not in Supabase. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/296#issuecomment-976200828) where the CTO of Supabase explains why, but exposing whether a certain user exists or not in public endpoint creates a security vulnerability.

`signUp()` method in Supabase will always behave the same on the client side whether there is already a user or not. On the backend, an email will be sent to the user, which will contain a confirmation link if the user did not exist prior, or a magic link if the user already did exist. If the user had already created an account and clicks on a magic link, the user is logged in as if they signed in using magic link, so no need to worry about anything further.

#### Original

I believe this would be the same in Firebase and Supabase (please correct me if I am wrong), but you will get an error if the user with the same email already existed.

You can get the error like this:

```dart
final response = await Supabase.instance.client.auth.signUp(email,pass);
final error = response.error;
if(error != null) {
  // Here you can handle case where there was an error signing up.
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, unless "Enable email confirmations" is turned off, supabase will return a fake user object and the error object will be null.

Refer note section of https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup

Comment: The problem is that successive signups don't send new verification emails, leaving the user completely clueless.